# MongoID relational queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I had these models

```
class State
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name    
  embeds_many :cities
end


class City
  include Mongoid::Document    
  field :name
  field :zip_code    
  embedded_in :state    
  references_many :organization_addresses
end

class Organization
  include Mongoid::Document    
  field :name    
  references_many :organization_addresses
end

class OrganizationAddress
  include Mongoid::Document    
  field :address
  field :latitude, :type=>Float
  field :longitude, :type=>Float    
  referenced_in :organization
  referenced_in :city
end
```

Now i want to create an address for an organization and reference that address to a city whose zip_code is  `06511`. First thing how can i find city which is embedded in state. and then how i can i reference it. I wrote query `State.where("cities.zip_code"=>"06511").count` It do not return any thing where as the city is there in the database.

How can i search it and then reference it to the address of the organization?

Comment: Hey Nazar, have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is two keep the id-s of the Cities inside State and then you can find the states which have certain id-s inside that array. You can implement difficult logic in there with IN, NIN (not in) keywords, etc.

I really recommend you to watch [this](http://www.10gen.com/presentation/mongosf2011/schemabasics) to get into it

Comment: Thanks man, it helps me to understand schema design in MongoDB.

Answer (score -1):

You can`t reference embedded documents in MongoID.